# Function that requires different syntax to "call"

Tags: discussion, answers

Is it allowed to submit a Python solution like the below:

```
{"a":"b"}
```

if the challenge is to output `b` if the input is `a`, and error otherwise? I could claim, "It is an anonymous function, it just requires a different syntax:"

```
f = {"a":"b"}
f[input()]
```

Is this a valid submission?

Comment: Regardless of syntax, in Python, `f` would not be a function, it would be a dictionary. Even the syntax used to *call* `f` is not the way a function is called in Python, which would be `f(x)` not `f[x]`.

Comment: I'd argue that, in this situation, the proper corresponding submission is `{"a":"b"}.__getitem__`.

Comment: I would say that if `{"a":"b"}` has the correct behavior as the submission for some challenge, it's a bad challenge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It's not a function (at least in this case)

No, it shouldn't be allowed, at least not as a "function".

Your submission is a hashmap, which isn't a function. Last time I checked I couldn't perform primality checking by accessing a hashmap (without hardcoding every number which is disallowed by [this loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1063/40695)).

---

[@Mego stated](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9317/function-that-requires-different-syntax-to-call#comment27437_9323) that python's '`collections.defaultdict`', can perform primality checking, and I'm guessing can add two numbers, and so it fulfills the definition of a function. But the again, python has functions, a hashmap simply is not a function.

Languages which have functions, those functions are the only functions. Anything else is not a function and is viable to abuse.

E.g. If "functions that get called in a different way", were allowed. Well, guess what? I have a solution that's called through eval! Huh,... I also have a function that's called through `prompt().split("").map((l,i,a)=><CODE HERE>)`.

So here's my stance:

**If it's not a function, it's not a function**

Pretty straightforward, eh?

Comment: With a `collections.defaultdict`, you can cleverly define the default value to calculate the primality. Not that it'd be shorter than a real function, but the point stands.

Comment: Just because this doesn't work for one specific problem doesn't mean it is invalid all the time. -1

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ updated to address Mego, and your points

Comment: @Mego I'm not so sure about the defaultdict point - if you define it so that the default value calculates primality then the submission should be the factory function you gave the defaultdict, not the dict itself surely?

Comment: @Sp3000 I never said it would be the shortest submission. In fact, I said the exact opposite in my first comment. I'm just saying it would be valid.

Comment: I think this logic is faulty.  We require *languages* to do primality testing, not *functions*.

Comment: @NathanMerrill if we allow functions as submissions, why should they not fulfill the definition of a programming language?

Comment: *(at least in this **cae**)* should be **case**.

Comment: @Upgoat because that doesn't have to be the case.  Say I create a language with a function, but that the function only can execute a single "command".  Depending on what a "command" is, that could mean that a *function* couldn't do primality testing, but that the program could.

Comment: @NathanMerrill a function that can only execute a single command? That's just the command itself, right? So you're saying if a challenge was "add two numbers", my (e.g. JavaScript) submission could be `+`? I'm going to stick to my definition rather than far-fetched hypotheticals.

Comment: @Upgoat not necessarily.  It totally depends on the syntax.  Say I wrote a language that was identical to C, but didn't allow curly braces.  While a factorial function would still be possible in such a language, we'd still consider the function in C still be a function.

Comment: Regardless of hypotheticals, we *currently* don't enforce functions to be capable of primality checking, and never have.  If we are going to make that a requirement of functions, then it needs to be on the [right meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8737/what-even-is-a-function-by-our-standards)

Comment: @NathanMerrill well in that case it would be a function, there's no debate about it. This and the definition of a function are jist for edge cases like these

Comment: I agree with Nathan - a function does not have to fulfill the programming language requirements; just the language. Consider a hypothetical language where the only operations functions can do are addition and subtraction of two integers. Clearly, the functions would not satisfy our requirements, but a program consisting of a collection of function definitions, variable assignments, and loops would be able to test primality, therefore satisfying our requirements.

Comment: @Mego I don't understand your point? You're saying for an "add two integers" challenge, a valid submission is the + operator which you are dubbing a "function"? A function isn't an operator. If a function can only do addition or subtraction why is it not an operator, and how is that a function?

Comment: @Upgoat I never said anything about operators. There's hardly any distinction between the two in many OOP languages, anyway (in C++ and Python, an operator is just a function with a funny name that is called inline with its arguments instead of in the traditional fashion). In this hypothetical language, operators need not be present. Let's give it 6 functions - `input`, `output`, `assign`, `isZero`, `add`, and `subtract`. Clearly those functions, along with a looping structure, are sufficient for primality testing, though each individual function is not.

Comment: @Mego I don't see how that's relevant. we're talking about the definition of a function. in your given hypothetical language, your "functions" are really operators. C++ and Python are not your hypothetical language so I don't see how they're relevant. Either way: how would you define a function in your hypothetical language. Shouldn't a function be allowed to consist of more than one operator? otherwise I fail to see how a function would be distinct from just the individual operator

Comment: @Upgoat I think you're missing the point of the hypothetical language. Perhaps I'll actually implement the language so you can understand better. In short: there are no operators in this language; only functions, even though they're the same.

Comment: In Ruby, you have methods (created in the current context by `def` and called with parentheses), procedures/lambdas (called with `.call` , square brackets or with `.(...)`) and blocks (proc literals that can be passed as implicit arguments to functions and called with `yield`). Surely at least the first two should be allowed?

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah those are of course allowed as they are functions/methods/lambdas(whatever they are called) as defined by the language, where (to my understanding), that's the language's designated/designed way to call it.

Comment: Let's say that a language doesn't distinguish between functions and strings, and to call a function you eval it. Would a string be a legal submission in that case? Why not in other languages then?

Comment: I have two objects, `foo` and `bar`. For both of them, `x[2]` returns `true` and `x["anything else"]` returns `false`. If we go by labels assigned by the language creators, only one of them is a valid submission in Ruby. Isn't it weird?

Comment: @JanDvorak that would be a difficult to consider case. But if the language defines this function/string mashup _as_ functions, or there is no definition of a function. And they fulfill our definition of a function, then it's ok. Though the part with the eval, I don't exactly get. You might want to check on the definition of a function and see if what you're saying complies with that

Comment: Are Haskell [arrows](https://www.haskell.org/arrows/) considered valid function submissions by your definition?

Comment: @JanDvorak They appear to fulfill the definition specified by this answer. I cannot understand what they actually do/how they work so I cannot tell if they would be able to fulfill our definition of a function.

Comment: So, why should an evaluable string be a valid submission in my Golfscript variant (where you set up the arguments on the stack and then eval the string) but not in Javascript (where you set up some local variables and then eval the string)? Golfscript does have a separate function type, but the only observable difference is during addition, where function addition separates tokens automatically while string addition does not. My golfscript variant removes strings and functions entirely (because functions are just strings with special addition and strings are just arrays with special printing).

Comment: And no, the difference is not because of how you pass arguments. `regcall` is not just a valid calling convention in c/assembly, but it's the fastest one available, and the only possibility in INTERCAL.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm sorry, I don't get your point. An evaluatable string is not valid whether in Golfscript, JavaScript, Jelly, or Java.

Comment: "But if the language defines this function/string mashup as functions, or there is no definition of a function. And they fulfill our definition of a function, then it's ok". my Golfscript variant clearly defines this array/string/function mashup to serve all three purposes. It also defines that to use it as a function you use the eval operator - and the if operator accepts two vectors (let's call chars/ints scalars, and arrays/strings/functions vectors), one of which it evals. So yes, according to your definition, it is a valid submission.

Comment: @JanDvorak the string array function mashup pose a problem in fulfilling our definition of a function. How would input be _directly_ passed to it?

Comment: You set up the stack and call eval. That's not any different from what functions in actual golfscript do. You have to use some kind of predefined storage if you don't have function arguments, and function arguments are nothing but special case predefined storage.

Comment: @JanDvorak setting up variables is not allowed by default. Cjam and GS blocks have been explicitly allowed and are exempt from the previous rule. If you truly believe your str/array/function mashup would qualify as a block, then you may attempt posting an answer with it but I doubt the community will agree with you

Comment: You have to put the arguments somewhere. If putting them to predefined spaces is disallowed, this disqualifiers assembly, as well as any stack based language. That is, a good portion of esolangs

Comment: Does this mean that an expression that evaluates to the correct output be valid in Kolmogorov-complexity challenges? I could say "It's called like a lisp function, `(expression)`!" (when in reality the parens do nothing).

Answer (score 11):

It's not a function in Python (since Python has functions, and that is objectively not a function), so you couldn't claim it is one.

However, in the mathematical sense, a `dict` (or any other mapping type) is a function (or close enough for our standards). Python `dict`s define a domain (with no repeated values), a codomain (with possibly repeated values), and a mapping from domain values to codomain values. That is *exactly* the [definition of a function in mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)). Specifically, it functions identically to a [partial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function), in which not all of the elements of the domain (i.e. every hashable Python object) have a mapping to elements of the codomain (though using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or the [`default` parameter of `dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) make it a total function).

Furthermore, they fulfill our [requirements for function submissions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8737/45941) - they are consistent and reusable.

As such, it is my opinion that mapping objects (such as Python `dict`s, C++ `std::map`s, and Java `java.util.HashMap`s) are valid function submissions.

Comment: What about an array or a list (provided that the "input" is an integer)? Many challenges are like "return the `n`th value that...", so may I simply return an array/list of all values and omit the indexing? E.g. for [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70615/34531) the last line of [my answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70624/34531) can be shortened to `g"1"`, saving 4 bytes.

Comment: @nimi Sure, an array or list is also a mapping type (with the domain being integers).

Comment: then I don't think it's a good idea to allow "mapping objects" as valid functions submissions.

Comment: @nimi Then we need a stricter definition of function that arrays and dictionaries don't satisfy, because they satisfy all of our requirements currently. I don't see a problem with allowing them.

Comment: Is your answer a "Yes it's acceptable" or "No it's not"? your first paragraph contradicts your last.

Comment: @Upgoat There's no contradiction. I'm saying it's not a function in the context of the language, but it fulfills our requirements for functions.

Comment: There's a definite contradiction. You say that it fulfils our requirements for function submissions, but the post you link to support that says "***if it's blatantly obvious it's not a function, it's not a function.***" and "***Python has functions. Anything else is not a function***"

Comment: @PeterTaylor I linked to the question, not the answer. None of the answers have sufficient votes to be considered consensus. The general idea that all of the votes-up answers share is that the code needs to be reusable, consistent, and independent. Dicts and lists satisfy those requirements.

Comment: Should there be a limit to the complexity of the "mapping object" and/or "access fucntion"? If so, where's the line? Some examples: a) simple arrays, accessed with bracket syntax `a[i]` b) association lists, i.e. lists of key-value pairs, accessed via a function (Lisp: `assoc`, Haskell: `lookup`, etc.) c) binary search trees, tries, etc. which have complex access functions (remember: code for retrieving elements is not part of the solution and is not included in the byte count) ...

Comment: ... d) anything from above but with additional data stored in the objects, say arrays of triples where the data for `i` is stored in the `ith` array element and 2nd element of the triple (example: given `i`, return `i` squared: answer: `[(0,1,0),(0,4,5),(3,9,8),(0,16,33)...]`). Any difference between built-in and user provided "mapping objects"?

Comment: @nimi What would be the purpose of limiting the complexity? If it maps inputs to outputs in such a manner that each input has exactly one output, it's a function. How it does the mapping is irrelevant.

Comment: @Mego: I could outsource computation to the access function. E.g. given `i`, return `i` squared, Haskell answer: `[0..]`. It just needs a special calling syntax: `\a i -> (a!!i)^2 `. In actual challenges, I sometimes augment list elements with additional data, do some calculations (e.g. sorting based on the additional data) and extract the original elements again. Can I outsource the extracting step to the caller?

Comment: @nimi "Outsourcing" the computation is a standard loophole: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1789/45941

Comment: Whether you think this specific example prssentd by the OP should be valid is another thing, but this opens up a whole new area, available to abuse. I could say my js solution is `prompt()-2` and it's run through `eval`. **There's no point in allowing what's not a function as a function** as this could be abused to such a high extent

Comment: @Upgoat That's still abusing the loophole I linked.

Comment: It's mot exactly outsourcing as the user doesn't enter the answer and all, but whether or not you call it valid, allowing _hashmaps_ as functions is just ridiculous. I can kind of understand it in more esoteric languages, but in langauges that have functions, those are functions. Allowing anythinf else just opens a whole world of abuse.

Comment: @Upgoat As our policies currently stand, mapping objects satisfy all of our requirements for functions. If you don't want them to be valid, you need a stronger argument than "they're not functions" or "look at how you can abuse these already-banned loopholes".

Comment: @Mego: "If you don't want them to be valid, you need a stronger argument than "they're not functions"". No! What counts as a function here on PPCG is purely defined by consensus. If we want to exclude data structures, it's enough to say "they're not functions". Why we want them to be excluded doesn't really matter. "Possible abuse" _is_ a reason - among others. And: we are discussing it here, in this thread. If the [other thread about functions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8737/45941) would be the only place to discuss at, then this one must be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @nimi If "potential for abuse" was a showstopper, then we wouldn't allow user-created programming languages. Instead, we take the more reasonable approach that allows user-created languages, but forbids certain kinds of abuse (creating a language specifically to solve a challenge, for example). "They're not functions" is not a strong argument either, because I detailed exactly why they are, in fact, functions, and that argument simply boils down to "I disagree", without providing any solid reasons.

Comment: @Mego: We (the community) decide what's a function and what's not a function by (down)voting for different proposals. One is [data structures are not functions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9323/34531) this one is "they are". Highest number of votes wins. Currently it's a standoff, so you argument "because I detailed exactly why they are" doesn't hold. It's undecided. "They are" if this answers wins, "they aren't" if the other answer wins. Maybe a third answer will come up with something in-between.

Comment: @nimi You're not getting it. I detailed exactly why they are functions in the mathematical sense, and satisfy all of our requirements for functions. If you don't believe they should be acceptable submissions, you must have a stricter idea of what constitutes a function than our current consensus.

Comment: @Mego: the stricter idea is: "mapping data structures are not functions, because we've said so". If the other answer wins, they do not satisfy our requirements, because they are explicitly banned. PPCG has it's own definition of functions, no need to look to mathematicians.

Comment: Let's muddy the water a bit more and let me make this a literal tie with my votes... 6:6

Answer (score 2):

Just because you can claim something, doesn't make you right. If you did claim that this was an anonymous function then you would be objectively wrong and your answer would quickly receive a lot of downvotes and votes for deletion as low quality.

Comment: This doesn't answer this question. Is it allowed, or not in your opinion? You're just saying it is not a function.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere By saying it isn't a function, it is implied that it is a code snippet, and we already have a policy regarding this :)

Comment: @NoOneIsHere, the wording of the question seems to be asking whether it is allowed to claim that "This is a function". Claiming that behaviour is justified because X where X is objectively false is (or should be) unacceptable behaviour in *any* community. To be honest, on revisiting the question I've downvoted because a) meta is for discussing real issues: this seems very artificial and can only be relevant in the context of a really poor quality question on main; b) this is a code golf and challenge community, not a rules-lawyer community.

Comment: This is asking about our standard for our community.